# Windows 8 Store Apps - BitmapImage

Tags: image, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I need to use BitMapImage framework in my Windows  Store Application. I need to create item in GridView and fill it by image. I know the following example:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
imagesGrid.Items.Add(img);
```

But, when I'm trying to use BitmapImage, I can't. Visual Studio doesn't have this object. I think i need to import framework, so does someone know that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BitmapImage` is in the `Imaging` namespace.  You need to use this include:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
```